# How do we feel about setting up a Discord server?

Tags: discussion

Often I want to have extended conversations with you all.  This platform is not good for conversations.  Being able to drop a link to a Discord server where such conversations could take place seems nice.  What do you all think?

https://discord.gg/urrYs6Xn

Comment: Is there are reason not to use Stack Exchange chatrooms?

Comment: The only reason not to use SE chat would be to avoid SE moderation; there is no plausible valid motive for moving public discussion between SE users to a non-SE service. It's been frequently described to me that SE chat is, while far from perfect and problematic in some ways, vastly better in terms of structuring conversation in an accessible and practical way than other commonly used or available chat services, so that may factor in as well.

Comment: @Nij SE chat is horrible.

Comment: @StevenGubkin at least it loads faster than Discord.

Answer (score 8):

Discord is very good in many ways. The biggest downside to Discord is that **the conversations are not publicly archived** in a searchable way.

In one of my hobbies, casual conversations between experts used to take place on forums. The natural evolution of that desire for well-archived conversations between experts is StackExchange itself.

Today, many casual conversations between experts happen on Discord, but those conversations are isolated from the rest of the internet -- no Google search reveals them, and when a Discord disappears, the conversations are lost to the public. When a forum disappears, the conversations are still archived at the Internet Archive.

This doesn't mean "don't create a Discord," of course, but it's worth mentioning.